button-click and web scraping
I trying to get the number of comments and content of comments  from : https://www.arlnow.com/
I have a problem for "load more comments" button.
I tried:
load_more_xpath = '//a[contains(text(), "Load more comments")]'
load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, load_more_xpath)))
load_more_button.click()


I tried different ways but I could not find proper findelement for the number of comments and the content of comments!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Assuming this is the element you want to click:

The targeted element(Load more comments) is wrapped within an IFRAME. In such cases, you need to first switch the driver context inside the IFRAME and then perform desired action.
See the code below to switch into the iframe and then click on the targeted button.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//iframe[contains(@id,'dsq-app')])[1]")))

load_more_xpath = '//a[contains(text(), "Load more comments")]'
load_more_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, load_more_xpath)))
load_more_button.click()

# Below line will come out of IFRAME context
driver.switch_to.default_content()

